# Extract age number in word to excel

Tags: excel

anyone can make me a vb tools or anything
That can extract this:

Agung/57 th/blablabla

Into table

Agung   57

Comment: What is logic to extract that. For other data always has a space after number?

Answer (score 0):

Without further detail it is hard to guess your actual problem. With current sample data `FILTERXML()` will give you desired result.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]"),"/"," ")
```

You can also use `LEFT()/Search()` combination like

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1),"/"," ")
```

[image]